# Zio, transform Seq[ZIO] to ZIO[Seq]

Tags: scala, zio

That may be a dumb question, but starting with ZIO, I cannot manage to convert a `Seq[ZIO]` to `ZIO[Seq]`:

```
def translate(keys: Seq[String], locales: Seq[Locale]):RIO[Translator, Seq[Translation]] = {
  for {
    service <- ZIO.environment[Translator]
  } yield {
    // service.translate produce a zio.Task[Translation]
    keys.map(k => service.translate(k, locales)
  }
}
```

> Required: RIO[Translator, Seq[Translation]]
>
> Found   : ZIO[Translator, Nothing, Seq[zio.Task[Translation]]

I tried `flatMap`, `flatten`, `collectAll` and `merge` but I was not able to get the expected result with anyone.

How can I transform a `Seq[ZIO[_, _, B]]` to a `ZIO[_, _, Seq[B]]` ?

Thanks

**Edit:** It seems that `ZIO.foreach` is the best option, however I still have it wrapped inside another ZIO due to the for comprehension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because for loops translate to `flatMap` except for the last line which is a `map`, you want to add the `foreach` call *within* the for-loop.

```
def translate(keys: Seq[String], locales: Seq[Locale]): RIO[Translator, Seq[Translation]] = { 
  for {
    translator <- ZIO.environment[Translator]
    translations <- ZIO.foreach(keys)(translator.translate(_, locales))
  } yield translations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you can do it using `traverse` function from `cats`:

```scala
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import zio.{RIO, Task, ZIO}
import zio.interop.catz._

import java.util.Locale

case class Translation()
trait Translator {
  def translate(k: String, locales: Seq[Locale]): Task[Translation]
}

def translate(keys: Seq[String], locales: Seq[Locale]): RIO[Translator, Seq[Translation]] = {
  val translator: Translator = ???
  for {
    service <- ZIO.effect(translator)
    result  <- keys.toList.traverse(k => service.translate(k, locales))
  } yield result
}
```

For map `List[ZIO[_, _, B]]` to `ZIO[_, _, List[B]]` you can use `sequence` function and I would advice to use `cats` library for that.

```scala
import zio.ZIO
import zio.interop.catz._
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.instances.list._

def ziosSequence[B](seqZIO: Seq[ZIO[Any, Throwable, B]]): ZIO[Any, Throwable, Seq[B]] = 
  seqZIO.toList.sequence.map(_.toSeq)
```

the `sequence` signature is:

```scala
def sequence[G[_]: Applicative, A](fga: F[G[A]]): G[F[A]] =
  traverse(fga)(ga => ga)
```

Here we see what function do what we need.
it requires `Applicative` instance for `G` (`G` is `ZIO` in your case), and we just import it using `import zio.interop.catz._`
Also, to make list is able to call `sequence` we need import `Traverse` instance for `List`:
by `import cats.instances.list._`
Unfortunetaly we can not do the same tricks with `Seq` because we need `Traverse` instance for `sequence`, and we should convert `Seq` to `List` back and forth before and after `sequence`.

useful links:

- [typelevel documentation cats.Traverse](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html)
- [typelevel documentation cats.Applicative](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicative.html)

Comment: This is technically correct, but importing the whole `cats` library for this is way overkill since ZIO defines its own combinators.

Comment: @francoisr you are right, maybe it's just more familiar only for me

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However, as said by @francoisr it looks a bit overkill and I was asking for a ZIO solution (while it may not be obvious).

Answer (score 0):

To "exchange" List and ZIO you could dance this way:

```
def dance(x: List[ZIO[Any,Throwable,Int]]): ZIO[Any, Throwable, List[Int]] = 
    x.map ( a => a.map(x=> List(x)))
    .fold ( ZIO.succeed(  List[Int]())  )
        ((x, y) => x.map(a => y.map(b => a ++ b ) )
            .flatten 
        )
```